# Pandas, converting date time column format's changes the column type

Tags: django, pandas, python-datetime

I have a data frame where I convert an object column to DateTime column.

```py
def insert_cows_to_db():
    df = pd.read_csv('/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/rivendell/dairyPlanExample.csv')
    df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])
    print(df)
    print(df.dtypes)
```

output:

```
        Cow   Transponder        DOB
0       NaN           NaN        NaT
1       8.0  9.840007e+14 2016-09-13
2       9.0  9.840007e+14 2014-07-09
3      13.0  9.840007e+14 2015-02-22
4      16.0  9.840007e+14 2014-02-17

Cow                   float64
Transponder           float64
DOB            datetime64[ns]
```

Now I want to change the date format for the column but when I use:

```py
def insert_cows_to_db():
    df = pd.read_csv('/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/rivendell/dairyPlanExample.csv')
    df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    print(df)
    print(df.dtypes)
```

output

```
        Cow   Transponder         DOB
0       NaN           NaN         NaN
1       8.0  9.840007e+14  13-09-2016
2       9.0  9.840007e+14  09-07-2014
3      13.0  9.840007e+14  22-02-2015
4      16.0  9.840007e+14  17-02-2014

Cow            float64
Transponder    float64
DOB             object
```

Is there a way to save the date-time object Because I then upload this data to DB in Django and the field there expects DateTime objects ( If I understand it's error correctly)

error when trying to upload to Django's DB

```
    match = date_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: what do you mean by *save the date-time object*? just don't use `strftime` to keep it as `datetime64[ns]`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert date to string in pandas via :

```
df['DOB'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

and then convert it back to django datetime field using :

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```